# Fancybox version 3 image autoplay

Tags: fancybox

this is my site http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/projects.html

What i want is when the thumbnail is clickked it will open up the fancybox, i want the image slideshow to autoplay, instead of needing to click left and right button.

I have tried inserting this code below in the css but does not seem to work

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
autoPlay : true, //  slideshow will start after opening the first gallery item
playSpeed : 3000 // 3sec pause between changing next item
});
```

FYI this is the latest version of fancybox and also pls advice on how to change speed of the slideshow.

Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1):

Seems this has been changing up quite a bit between v2, v3, and v3.1 - hope this helps.  Change your selectors as needed.

```
//Worked for me in v3.0.47
$('[data-fancybox="group1"],[data-fancybox="group2"]').fancybox({
    onActivate : function($instance) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $instance.SlideShow.start();    
        },500);     
    }
});

//Worked for me in v3.1.19      
$('[data-fancybox="group1"],[data-fancybox="group2"]').fancybox({
    slideShow : {
        autoStart : true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use options from v2, but they do not exist in v3. Auto start of slideshow will be available from v3.1

Comment: When will v3.1 be out ? So if cannot do autoplay with fancybox, what other alternatives do i have?

Comment: Is this really so crucial for you? :) If you can not wait, then you can grab first beta from here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/pPRvwv?editors=1000 - it is quite ready and I am now working on documentation

Comment: Yup it is crucial for me because of my dumb client, who insist on having autoplay images as if his company will go bankrupt if it doesnt. Thanks man!

Comment: Hi @janis. So what do i do with that link ? How do i download the v3.1 ?

Comment: Either grab js and css from that codepen or wait next week when it will be available from GitHub

Comment: Hi, can the fancybox 3.0 now autoplay and also the right and left navigation to be on the side of the image. Thanks!

Comment: You would have to upgrade to v3.1; you can get code from GitHub; See demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmBLrN

Comment: Hi, where do i download the 3.1 file? In the github demo i only see the HTML and CSS. This is my page that need to use fancybox http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/projects.html   Now my page is using the script <script src="fancybox-3.0/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script> Where do i get the 3.1? Do i just have to dl latest file from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/ ?

Comment: fancyBox uses branches for versioning -
 https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/tree/3.1